# Which cyrillic fonts are featured in iPhone-sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

I'm developing apps for iOS and I would like to know which fonts I can use to Cyrillic texts. The problem is that not all of the standard English fonts are featured. Could you please give a list cyrillic supported fonts for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone ever compiled such a list of only Cyrillic supporting fonts, however you can always bring your custom font with you:

See UIAppFonts settings key here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

It allows to add custom fonts and then use them with UIFont in your application.